# Make a txt file in internal storage in android

Tags: android, android-file

i want to make one folder on root and put txt file and append data 
'

My java code

```
  public void generateNoteOnSD(String sFileName, String sBody){
        try
        {
            String fileName = "error";
            String headings = "Hello, world!";
            String path = "/data/root/";
            File file = new File(path, fileName+".txt");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdirs();
            }
            File gpxfile = new File(file, sFileName);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
            writer.append(sBody);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
           // Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.d("file error", ""+e.getMessage());
        }
       }
```

I am getting file not found exception

Please help me how can create a file on root folder in internal storage

Comment: You can't unless your phone is rooted, you don't have access to that directory (you don't even have the right access to the /data directory to make it).

If you are rooted, your app needs to run as root to make it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this function.

```
public void wrtieFileOnInternalStorage(Context mcoContext,String sFileName, String sBody){
    File file = new File(mcoContext.getFilesDir(),"mydir");
    if(!file.exists()){
        file.mkdir();
    }

    try{
        File gpxfile = new File(file, sFileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append(sBody);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

Comment: change "mydir" to your folder name

Comment: but you can not crate folder in root folder

Comment: the above folder is created in application storage and can not be visible and accesible to any other application

Comment: need  to open txt file manually but i did not find out txt file in phone

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this -

```
public Boolean writeToSD(String text){
        Boolean write_successful = false;
         File root=null;  
            try {  
                // <span id="IL_AD8" class="IL_AD">check for</span> SDcard   
                root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  
                Log.i(TAG,"path.." +root.getAbsolutePath());  

                //check sdcard permission  
                if (root.canWrite()){  
                    File fileDir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath());  
                    fileDir.mkdirs();  

                    File file= new File(fileDir, "samplefile.txt");  
                    FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(file);  
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);  
                    out.write(text);  
                    out.close();  
                    write_successful = true;
                }  
            } catch (IOException e) {  
                Log.e("ERROR:---", "Could not write file to SDCard" + e.getMessage());  
                write_successful = false;
            }  
        return write_successful;
    }
```

From here - http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/09/06/read-write-files-sdcard-application-sandbox-android-complete-example/

Answer (score 1):

In this statement:

```
File gpxfile = new File(file, sFileName);
```

file should be directory (you use `.txt` file here).

Also, read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal). You can store you file in `/data/data/<your.package.name>/` dir (trying to use `/data/root/` will cause *Permission denied* error).

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Using this, I have created log file in SD card.

```
public void writeFile(String text){

    File tarjeta = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File logFile = new File(tarjeta.getAbsolutePath()+"/", "log.txt");
    if (!logFile.exists())
    {
        try
        {
            logFile.createNewFile();
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try
    {
        //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
        BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
        buf.append(text);
        buf.newLine();
        buf.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```