# App crashes when shared and works fine when tested using debug mode

Tags: android

I have tested my app on several devices

> Jelly bean, Kitkat, Lollipop, Marshmallow

Using debugging directly from my app and also sharing from one mobile to another mobile.

It is working absolutely fine in all mobile phones in both ways(Excluding one)

I have one **kitkat(4.4.4)** Moto G phone in which the app is working fine as in other devices but when I share this app and run, then the app **crashes** before it opens.

Don't know what to do since I can't know what could be the error since running using **usb debugging** is working fine.

My Gradle Build

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24

    }
    buildTypes {

        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
        }
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: post error log...

Comment: @Divyesh Hi Divyesh but error log from where?

Comment: @Divyesh app is running fine with usb debugging but crashes when shared so I guess I don't know where the error will be generated since I have no knowledge of apk error log in mobile.....and in onCreate of first activity I guess I am not calling any api also which would generate an error if I am on a different network in which the api is made

Comment: add analytic service in app. like fabric

Comment: how do you share ? using another app ?? try email and see if it still  occurs integrate   crash reporting tool http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/drafts/106510

Comment: @Charuka sharing app using shareIT but the problem is not with sharing medium since I am sharing app on other mobile and it is working fine.......I also tried on this moto g to share the apk in shareit folder which it receive from another mobile then also it is working fine

Comment: @Divyesh which fabric ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also faced this issue and the only working solution I could find was to disable `instant run` from settings in android studio. and then do a clean build and generate a new `app-debug.apk`. share this apk with multiple devices

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted instant run is showing up after I upgraded my studio recently........but still crash reporting is important to implement......

Comment: install the apk, then plug the kitkat phone with pc and then you can get the logcat crash report

Comment: Well it worked and do you know I had to remove that debug{minifyEnable true} from my gradle too since there was some error and when I used instant run then this debug was not causing any problem.....not getting what's happening

Comment: not sure, I have never used `minifyEnable true` in debug builds.

Comment: But I have to know what was causing the crash because of instant run being enabled....well if i know something on it i'll comment here about the issue

Answer (score 0):

This is not direct solution toy your question, but it will help you to find solution for any crash of your app.

Add CustomExceptionHandler class which will write log for any crash in app

```
public class CustomExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {

private UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;

private String localPath;

private String url;

/* 
 * if any of the parameters is null, the respective functionality 
 * will not be used 
 */
public CustomExceptionHandler(String localPath) {
    this.localPath = localPath;
    this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
}

public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
    String timestamp = TimestampFormatter.getInstance().getTimestamp();
    final Writer result = new StringWriter();
    final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(result);
    e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
    String stacktrace = result.toString();
    printWriter.close();
    String filename = timestamp + ".stacktrace";

    if (localPath != null) {
        writeToFile(stacktrace, filename);
    }


    defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e);
}

private void writeToFile(String stacktrace, String filename) {
    try {
        BufferedWriter bos = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                localPath + "/" + filename));
        bos.write(stacktrace);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

And add this code in mainActivity

```
if(!(Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() instanceof CustomExceptionHandler)) {
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CustomExceptionHandler(
        "/sdcard/<desired_local_path>"));
}
```

Hope this will help you...!

Comment: and where will I see this app log here --> sdcard/<desired_local_path>", "http://<desired_url>/upload.php"

Comment: what this will do pls elaborate Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CustomExceptionHandler(
        "/sdcard/<desired_local_path>", "http://<desired_url>/upload.php"));

Comment: it means, log file generate and send it to php file server

Comment: Please make sure that when you paste code from other sources you modify it to answer the particular question.. The above code needs to be modified to only write to local file and not send data to any server.

Comment: @akash93 Yeah but if remove this "http://<desired_url>/upload.php" then will it write only to the file I mean second args I dont need to write?

Comment: he needs to remove the url parameter from the constructor and `if url !=null` block. Till my edit is approved you can't see it. For now just pass `null` as 2nd parameter

Comment: @Divyesh I need to write file in internal storage and where will write in which file ? which format

Comment: @Divyesh give me the full path example and do I need to create a text file manually before running and writing error log

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24751910/6756514  and make sure check for storage permission on marshmalloe

Comment: @Divyesh the problem is with this one specific device while on other it is working fine I have already tested on marshmallow both ways

Comment: then add fabric in app. it manage your app and notify when app crashes

Comment: @Divyesh The fabric which charuka have posted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133430/discussion-between-divyesh-and-samh67).

Comment: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-fabric-crashlytics-integration/

Comment: Sorry guys...I was in hurry, but next time I'll make sure to check the code before posting..!! Sorry for inconvenience.